# Why is JSS not used to load Roboto in material-ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

Material-UI uses JSS way to style their components. It is built with "roboto" font keeping in mind. But, to load this Roboto font, why is Material-UI depending on CSS module like "typeface-roboto"? Does this contradict in a way they use JSS to style components and CSS for font family?

Answer (score 1):

Material-UI provide customization. It's not madentory to use roboto font. We can customize style and font globally in create theme section. Roboto font is default font style for material-UI, which is suggested but if we include always this font and someone wan't other font than roboto font use unessary space in app. We should avoid this.

To use roboto font, we can import typeface-robot css or we can put roboto font cdn css url

Comment: Yes, I was particularly asking why to use typeface-roboto CSS? Aren't there any other npm modules which have roboto font-face declaration in form of JSS?

Comment: It's not mandatory, It's suggested. If you found any other library similar typeface-roboto, You can use that.